# How to read 4th order mixed Leibniz derivative

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

How exactly is the order of mixed partials read in Leibniz notation?
In Lagrange notation, we just read from left to right.

$$f_{xyzz} = \left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
But what would the compacted form of Leibniz be?
$$? = \left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
Here are some options that I have seen, but don't know which one is right, it seems each person I ask/website I visit has its own convention for these rather odd/rarely used cases
$$\frac {\partial^4f} {\partial z^2 \partial y \partial x} = \left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
$$\frac {\partial^4f} {\partial x \partial y \partial z^2} = \left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
I personally feel that the latter is more intuitive, since it would mean both Lagrange's subscripts and Leibniz's denominator have the same order

$$f_{xyzz} = \frac {\partial^4f} {\partial x \partial y \partial z^2} =\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial z}\left(\frac {\partial} {\partial y}\left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are conventions, but the most usual way is:
$$f_{xyzz}\equiv\frac{\partial^4f}{\partial z^2\partial y\partial x}$$
Note that:
$$f_{xyzz}\equiv\left(\left(\left(f_x\right)_y\right)_z\right)_z$$
$$\frac{\partial^4f}{\partial z^2\partial y\partial x}\equiv\frac\partial{\partial z}\left(\frac\partial{\partial z}\left(\frac\partial{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\right)\right)$$